# change adapter of ListView after each search letters

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I develop a ListView which display a product list with a title and the list is in CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE.

I pet an EditText on the top of the listView to allow to search a product letters by letters.
So the research work well but there are not the same number of product.
So the problem is after a search when i click on an item, the wrong product is selected because the listview keep the position in function to the list_data.

For example : 
               Before any search i choose the item and the system take the good item
[image]

But if i do a search , the listview rebuild with a new list of data in function the letters which is enter.

[image]

So like you see, i choosed the product with name BA300 and the system take BA03D.
I think it's a problem with adapter , that the listview keep the first adapter with all item in the setOnItemClickListener(),  whereas i set the adapter with a new list item to rebuild the listview.

```
///////////////////////////Method to create and display a pop-up with list of allproduct/////////

public void openListAllProduct(final FormField field){

    ArrayList<String> list_datas = new ArrayList<String>();

    ProductQuery productQuery = new ProductQuery(this);
    productQuery.open();        
    list_datas = productQuery.getAllProduct();
    productQuery.close();

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ViewPdf.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.list_all_product);       
    final ListView list_view = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.list_prod);
    final EditText search_product = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.search_product);
    final EditText quantity_product = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.quantity_product);        
    final TextView TVProduct = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TVproductAll);

    search_product.setSingleLine();
    dialog.setTitle("Tous les produits");   

    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN); 
    quantity_product.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, list_datas);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////      
list_view.setAdapter(modeAdapter); <----ITS THE FIRST ADAPTER WITH ALL ITEM
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    list_view.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);       
    list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {               
            Log.i("Product :",quantity_product.getText() + " " + modeAdapter.getItem(position));
            item_lv = modeAdapter.getItem(position).toString();
            TVProduct.setText(item_lv);
        }
    });
    ///si le field n'est pas remplie alors on désactive le bouton supprimer
    if(!field.isEmpty()){

        String[] datas_product = ((TextField) field).getValue().split(" ");
        quantity_product.setText(datas_product[0]);
        TVProduct.setText(datas_product[1]);
    }
    search_product.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            ProductQuery productQuery = new ProductQuery(ViewPdf.this);
            productQuery.open();        
            final ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ViewPdf.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, productQuery.getProductByChar(s.toString()));
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            list_view.setAdapter(modeAdapter); <-- THE SECOND ADAPTE WITH NEW LIST OF DATAS
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            list_view.invalidateViews(); <---- rebuild the listView

            productQuery.close();               
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {}           
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    });


    ////bouton pour revenir à la popup produit/contrat
    Button dialog_button_return = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_return);     
    dialog_button_return.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            dialog.dismiss();
            openListProductContractClient(R.layout.list_product_by_contract,field,0);
        }
    });

    ////bouton pour valider la sélection
    Button dialog_button_validate = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_validate_all_product);     
    dialog_button_validate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            try {

                if(quantity_product.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    quantity_product.setText("1");
                }
                if(list_view.getCheckedItemPosition() == AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION){                         
                    if(!TVProduct.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                        ((TextField) field).setValue(quantity_product.getText() + " " + TVProduct.getText().toString());
                    }

                }else{
                    ((TextField) field).setValue(quantity_product.getText() + " " + item_lv);
                }


            } catch (PDFException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });


    dialog.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i resolved my problem.

Finally in the setOnItemClickListener i use the variable parent to get the position , that all. i thought that it's was more difficult.. =)

```
list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {               
            Log.i("Product :",quantity_product.getText() + " " + modeAdapter.getItem(position));
            //item_lv = modeAdapter.getItem(position).toString();
            item_lv = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            TVProduct.setText(item_lv);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change the list of adapter you should call the method of adapter.

```
notifyDataSetChange();
```

With your adapter object 
I hoping it will help you.